# Is it possible to make a Load balancer (ELB) only be accessed by SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, internal-load-balancer

I'm creating an internal application load balancer in AWS. I want it to be available/reachable only by SNS and blocking every other request.

I tried looking for the SNS IP's used by AWS (so I can whitelist only those) but there isn't a reliable range.

Is there any way to do this?

PS.
I'm using cloudformation

Comment: What do you mean by "used by SNS"? Amazon Simple Notification Service does not "use" a database.

Comment: Are you intending to use the load balancer to receive HTTP notifications from SNS? If yes, then you can't use an internal load balancer, because it doesn't accept requests from the Internet. And there is probably a better solution to your actual question, but you need to tell us what that question is.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I mean that only SNS is allowed to make request to the ELB. (everything else is blacklisted)

Comment: @kdgregory Oh. So an Internal Load balancer cannot receive HTTP request from SNS? If that the case you know how can I achieve my goal? (as the question said, blacklisting everything else apart from SNS)

Comment: You can't. What is the _real_ problem that you're trying to solve, and what is the threat that you're trying to prevent?

Comment: @EduLopez Why do you wish to send SNS messages to the Load Balancer? Can you just bypass SNS and send it directly to the Load Balancer? What is the actual architecture you are wanting to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **subscribe an HTTP Endpoint** to an Amazon SNS topic.

You could use a Load Balancer's DNS Name as the endpoint, so messages would be sent to the Load Balancer. The Load Balancer will need to be in a **public subnet** because Amazon SNS is on the Internet.

You will also need to **confirm the subscription** via a link that SNS sends to the endpoint. (See [Using Amazon SNS for System-to-System Messaging with an HTTP/S Endpoint as a Subscriber](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html))

To "limit" the ability to send traffic to the Load Balancer so that only Amazon SNS can send requests, you can **configure a security group on the Load Balancer**. However, Amazon SNS is *not* listed in the `ip-ranges.json` file in [AWS IP Address Ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html), so you won't know which IP addresses to permit as inbound traffic.

You could experiment a bit to see what IP addresses SNS appears to use, then assign a larger CIDR range, but this is not guarantee that you will know all possible IP addresses. Therefore, your only other hope is to *not* restrict access, but risk the possibility of some other system/person sending traffic to the Load Balancer.

**Alternative Design**

Instead of sending message from Amazon SNS through the Load Balancer to your application (presumably running on Amazon EC2 instances), you could **redesign your application to use an Amazon SQS queue**:

- Subscribe an Amazon SQS queue to the Amazon SNS topic
- Have your application **poll the SQS queue for messages** (instead of waiting to receive messages via HTTP and Load Balancer)

Comment: Hey John, I believe you're incorrect in saying that SNS "is on the Internet." You can use SNS privately on a virtual private cloud, from what I gather, according to this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-vpc-tutorial.html

Comment: @drone1 Yes, you can add a _VPC Endpoint for Amazon SNS_ to a VPC to obtain access to Amazon SNS. However, that is for sending _to_ Amazon SNS. This particular question is about Amazon SNS contacting the Load Balancer, which would come from Amazon SNS via the Internet. It wouldn't be possible to direct such communication via the VPC Endpoint _into_ the VPC.